# Функция mail не отправляет письма, когда в сообщении присутствуют пробелы

Tags: php, email

Функция mail не отправляет письма, когда в сообщении присутствуют пробелы

Comment: Для $message есть некоторые другие ограничения, почитайте на php.net. Возможно, именно они мешают отправке.

Comment: Все ограничения соблюдены. Думаю хостер дебил, поведения функции mail на нем вообще не предсказуемо...

Comment: используйте библиотеки для отправки почты, к примеру phpmailer
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

В таких вариантах можно использовать отправку писем с помощью сокетов через SMTP сервера gmail или Яндекс. Подробно прочитать можно тут http://fakir.name/mail-php-ssl/

Comment: Которые будут работать только при условии, что в поле From: будет стоять адрес на gmail или yandex. А это далеко не всегда приемлемо, особенно если речь идёт о почте организации.

Comment: как правило организации используют почту яндекса или гугла, так что для большинства это подойдет. более того, можно настроить и на любой другой smtp

Answer (score 0):

Отписал в тех. поддержку хостинга, что у них проблема с меил сервером и они всё исправили. Так и не узнал конкретную причину неправильной работы функции.

Comment: @Jeremen1 возможно на хостинге стоит спам-фильтр и он неправильно обрабатывал сообщения.